# This Program has an error. could anybody help me to solve it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE(@x float, @y float)

SET @x = SELECT [Return] x 
         FROM [return] 
         WHERE YM BETWEEN 8801 AND 8901 
           AND Radif = 2

SET @y = SELECT [Return] y 
         FROM [return] 
         WHERE YM BETWEEN 8801 AND 8901 
           AND Radif = 2

;WITH cteSource(x, xAvg, y, yAvg, n) AS 
(
    SELECT  
        1E * x,
        AVG(1E * x) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)),
        1E * y,
        AVG(1E * y) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)),
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM    
        @Sample
)
SELECT  
    SUM((x - xAvg) *(y - yAvg)) / MAX(n) AS [COVAR(x,y)]
FROM
    cteSource
```

Comment: What error does it have? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

It probably has multiple errors.  But starting with the first three lines not making any sense:

```
DECLARE @Sample  table( @x float , @y float)
        set @x = SELECT [Return]x FROM  [return] where  YM between 8801 and 8901 and Radif=2
        set @y = SELECT [Return]y FROM  [return] where  YM between 8801 and 8901 and Radif=2;
```

Nearest I can guess, you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @Sample  table(x float, y float);
INSERT INTO @Sample(x, y )
    SELECT x, y
    FROM [return] 
    WHERE YM between 8801 and 8901 and Radif = 2;
```

(This may not be what you want.  It is only a guess.)

The first three lines have so many errors that my best advice is to brush up on T-SQL coding and SQL syntax.